# How to map own register operands in llvm-tablegen to instruction's opcode?

Tags: assembly, llvm, opcode

I'm trying to implement "address register with offset"-type operands. They consist of base registers and offset registers: [K1 + K3]. However in instruction's opcode I need to keep code for those register separately. I found no way of
1) Getting code of operand (is that a thing?)
2) Mapping Reg:$Rm, Reg:$Rn of operand to Rm and Rn fields of instruction directly. I'm getting Rm placed in slot for Rn and Rn merely ignored.

So how to get this thing done?

When i try to add them via BuildMI and print code they seem to be written correctly, so I guess those operands are parsed properly.

Operands description

```
def MemRRAsmOperand : AsmOperandClass {
  let Name = "MemRR";
  let ParserMethod = "parseMEMOperand";
}

class MemRR<RegisterOperand Reg> : Operand<i32>
{
  let MIOperandInfo = (ops Reg:$Rm, Reg:$Rn); <--- --- ---
  let ParserMatchClass = MemRRAsmOperand;
}

let PrintMethod = "printMemOperand" in
{
  def memJJ : MemRR<RegisterOperand<JSS>>;
  def memKK : MemRR<RegisterOperand<KSS>>;
}
```

Instruction description

```
class IALULoadStoreInstBase<dag outs, dag ins, string mnemonic, string operands, list<dag> pattern> :
  MyInst<outs, ins, mnemonic, operands, pattern>
{

    ...

  bits<5> Ureg; 
  bits<5> Rn; 
  bits<5> Rm; 

    ...
//IType is opcode
  let IType{25-21} = Group;  
  let IType{20-16} = Ureg;

  let IType{15} = MOD;
  let IType{14} = LQ;
  let IType{13} = ImmFlag;

  let IType{12-8} = Rm; <--- --- ---
  let IType{7-6} = 0b00;
  let IType{5-1} = Rn; <--- --- ---
  let IType{0} = Q;
   ...

}
```

Multiclass where I fill flags and pass out's and ins'es

```
multiclass IALULoadInstDst<RegisterOperand Dst, string mnemonic, string prefix, ValueType Type>
{
  let WR = 0 in
  {
    let JK = 0 in
    {
      let MOD = 0 in
      {
        defm fromJrr : IALULoadStoreRRInstEx<(outs Dst:$Ureg), (ins memJJ:$src), <--- --- ---
                                             !strconcat(mnemonic, "fromjrr"), !strconcat("$Ureg, ", prefix, "[$src]"), <--- --- ---
                                             [(set Type:$Ureg, (load addr:$src))]>; <--- --- ---
      }
    }
    let JK = 1 in
    {
      let MOD = 0 in
      {
        defm fromKrr : IALULoadStoreRRInstEx<(outs Dst:$Ureg), (ins memKK:$src), <--- --- ---
                                             !strconcat(mnemonic, "fromkrr"), !strconcat("$Ureg, ", prefix, "[$src]"), <--- --- ---
                                             [(set Type:$Ureg, (load addr:$src))]>; <--- --- ---
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own selection code for such operands. Such patterns are called "Complex" and you need to write custom instruction selection code for them. See e.g. X86DAGToDAGISel::SelectAddr() or SystemZDAGToDGAISel::selectBDAddr() and around.